# How to find template path in Flask if the templates folder is not under the same root of the .py files?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

Currently, im using the code

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)[:-4] + 'templates'))
```

but it seems so dumb.
I want to ask if there is an equivalent code to replace this?

BTW I have tried

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../flask-WTF/templates))
```

but this is not working.

My files structure is:
[file-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CksIx.png)

Answer (score 0):

you should have written:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../templates'))
```

also, you can try:

```
os.chdir('..')
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder = os.getcwd() + '/templates'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful